# Why after Downgrading IE10 to IE8 I lost access to Internet

Tags: proxy, internet-connection, internet-explorer-8

I can open localhost pages hosted on my IIS, but I can no longer access google neither my company services.

What is the problem? By downgraded IE10 to IE8 I lost configurations?

Do you have any idea?

I compared my ProxyServer value on the registry key [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings] with the one my colleague has and they are the same, still he can access everything but I can't.

Any clue? Thank you a lot!

Comment: How did you downgrade? Have you tried re-upgrading? What operating system?

Comment: Because all computers at the office use IE 8 and we cant upgrade them at the moment. So I need to test my development on IE 8, that's why the downgrade. And actually I am using a VM, but I don't think that's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try this:

1. Launch IE8
2. Tools > Internet Options > **'Restore advanced
   settings'** and **'Reset Internet explorer settings'**.
3. Restart IE8

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will try it and give feedback later. I am using VM , but I think this was working before the downgrade. Thank you

Comment: It worked! I have connection now! amazing! thanks!

Comment: @DarkLink Glad I could help! Even if this was a 'comment' and not an 'answer', I'll settle for the term **'solution'**.